# How to fetch values from meteor subscribe variable

Tags: mongodb, meteor

**Server :**

```
dbHandleremp = new Meteor.Collection("emp");
Meteor.publish("emp", function(email) {  
 return dbHandleremp.find({ 
 "email": email 
});
});
```

**client :**

```
dbHandleremp = new Meteor.Collection("emp");
var dbempQuery =Meteor.subscribe('emp', "a@a.com", function() {
dbHandleremp.find(); 
});
console.log(dbempQuery);
```

**how to get the values from "dbempQuery"**

Answer (score 1):

```
if(Meteor.subscribe('emp', "a@a.com").ready()){
  var result = emp.find({}).fetch();
  console.log(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Meteor.subscribe("emp", "a@a.com",{
  onReady: function () {
     var dbempQuery = emp.find({}).fetch();
     console.log(dbempQuery);
  }
});
```